# How to do in Objective C for iPhone what ZoneTag does?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

See this description?

"The ZoneTag client runs as a background process, monitoring the cell tower to which the phone is currently connected (which provides a rough location) and possibly communicating via BlueTooth to a GPS device, providing much more exact location information (and also providing a mapping between cell tower and physical location.)"

OK, how do we do that in Objective C on the iPhone? ZoneTag is used by Yahoo's Flickr service.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to resort to such trickery with the iPhone. Register as location based service for multitasking support. You can get heading info, tower info, and even more fine grained info on the iPhone4. Your app will still run in the background, and there's a document for that in the portal.